# Difference between these two logical expression

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let S(x) be the predicate “x is a student,” F(x) the predicate “x is a
>   faculty member,” and A(x, y) the predicate “x has asked y a question,”
>   where the domain consists of all people associated with your school.
>   Use quantifiers to express each of these statements. f ) Some student
>   has asked every faculty member a question.

What is the difference between 
 $\forall y(F(y)\to\exists x(S(x)\land A(x,y)))$
 and  $\exists x (S(x) \land \forall y(F(y)\to A(x,y)))$? A'int they same?

Comment: Maybe you want to read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: For the first statement, did you mean $∀y(F(y)→∃x(S(x)∧A(x,y)))$?

Answer (score 1):

In the first one you are saying: "For every faculty member, there exists a student...", whereas in the second one you are saying: "There is a student, and for all faculty members...". In this question we want the student to be fixed.

Also, the first one seems to actually read: "For all people y, if y is a faculty member then there exists a person x such that x is a student or x has asked y a question".

Answer (score 1):

The first : Every faculty member was questioned by (at least) one student. The second : Some student asked every faculty member....

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Just read it out loud. The first says (simplified): "For every faculty member $y$, there is a student that asked $y$ a question". The second formula reads "There is a student that asked every faculty member a question".

Answer (score 0):

The textbook answer says that the following represents:

> Some student has asked every faculty member a question.

$\forall y(F(y) \to  \exists x (S(x) \land A(x,y))) $

Which seems incorrect as I read this as saying for every faculty member there exists a student that has asked a question.
I'd argue that the following is more correct:

$\exists x (S(x) \land \forall y (F(y) \to A(x,y))) $